# How to change the button color on click?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular6

I have change iconic button color when clicking on it, default iconic button color is primary color when I clicked on the iconic button it should change primary color to red color. That working fine for me, now after clicking the hidden buttons will display one is cancel button  and other is save button up to here it is working fine now, when I clicked cancel button the button which is red color should change to primary but cancel button is closing and color of the iconic button is not changing

```js
<kendo-grid-command-column headerClass="data-list-header-cell" title="Delete" width="5" filterable="false">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-site>
      <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="onDelete(data)" [ngClass]="{'selectedRemoveButton':data.isClicked}">
        <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
      </button>
      
      // these are icon button if clicked on this button it will change color and also show 2 buttons cancel and save.
      
      <ng-container *ngIf="showButtons">
    <span class="rightButtons">
      <button class="mat-button menu-button" (click)="cancel()">
        <mat-icon>block</mat-icon> CANCEL
      </button>
      <button class="mat-button primary-button" (click)=" save()">
        SAVE
      </button>
    </span>
  </ng-container>
```

```css
.selectedRemoveButton {
  color: red
}
```

```html
 onDelete(data: any) {
    if (data.isClicked) {
      this.dataList.push(data);
    }
    data.isClicked = !data.isClicked;
    this.showButtons = !this.showButtons;
    console.log(data.Id);
  }
  
  //these is where i am first clicking on button when i click on these button color will change to red
  
  cancel(): void {
    this.showButtons = false;
  }
  //if presse on cancel button is disappearing but color have to change red to primary
  save() {
   
      this.Service.datalist(data.Id).subscribe(
          data => {
            this.dataList = data;
            console.log(data);
          });
    
  }
  //this is save button
```

please help me in this

Comment: tip: it is recommended to use [renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) API for DOM manipulation

Answer (score 0):

use `ngClass` to add classes dynamically.

```
<button class="mat-button menu-button" [ngClass]="removeStyles" (click)="cancel()">

removeStyles = "";
cancel(): void {
  this.showButtons = false;
  this.removeStyles= "selectedRemoveButton"
}
```

Comment: actually, I need primary color which I applied from HTML and in that case, I can't write CSS for cancel button

Comment: `this.removeStyles= "primary-button"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting that change is because you miss something there. 
Try to approach it adding a variable at the time you click on the button, like this.

```
[ngClass]="changBtnColor ? classNameColorActual : classNameColorAfterClick" (click)="changeColor()"
.classNameColorActual{ color:red} 
.classNameColorAfterClick{color:blue}
```

Meaning that the function

```
changeColor(): void {
     this.changBtnColor = !this.changBtnColor ;     // this should change the color of the 
                                     // button every time is clicked
  }
```

You should use a custom class to give them the styles but if you don’t want it you should also use the native classes of the element, to achieve this go to dev tools in chrome and search that class. 
I hope it should help you.